# Javascript - One-liner to extract values from object to array

Tags: javascript

I quite simple one:

I have a Javascript object with some properties whose values are arrays, with the following structure:

```
let obj = {emails: ["xxx@yyy.com", "qqq@www.com"], nickname: ["asdf"],...}
```

I need to get an array of arrays with only the values, like the following:

```
let obj2 = [["xxx@yyy.com"], ["qqq@www.com"], ["asdf"],...]
```

With `Object.values(obj)`, I get `[["xxx@yyy.com", "qqq@www.com"], ["asdf"],...]`, which is not exactly what I am looking for, but it is a good starting point...

Also, I am looking for a one-liner to do it, if possible. Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to flatten JS object (keys and values) to a single depth array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44134212/best-way-to-flatten-js-object-keys-and-values-to-a-single-depth-array)

Comment: This is not the same, I only need the values (not the keys), and each one in a separate array...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Object.values` to get array of values and then `concat` and spread syntax `...` to get flat array and then `map` method.

```js
let obj = {emails: ["xxx@yyy.com", "qqq@www.com"], nickname: ["asdf"]}
const values = [].concat(...Object.values(obj)).map(e => [e])
console.log(values)
```

Comment: Edited the question one sec ago

Comment: Works like a charm, and in one line. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

An alternative using the function `reduce`.

*This approach adds objects and arrays from the first level.*

As you can see, this approach evaluates the type of the object.

```js
let obj = {emails: ["xxx@yyy.com", "qqq@www.com"], nickname: ["asdf"]}

var result = Object.values(obj).reduce((a, c) => {
  if (Array.isArray(c)) return a.concat(Array.from(c, (r) => [r]));
  return a.concat([c]);
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

One line approach (excluding the checking for array type):

```js
let obj = {emails: ["xxx@yyy.com", "qqq@www.com"], nickname: ["asdf"]},
    result = Object.values(obj).reduce((a, c) => (a.concat(Array.from(c, (r) => [r]))), []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: The output does not match the way OP wanted it.

Comment: Edited the question one sec ago

Comment: Thanks. Although the other answer was a one-liner.