# How to Convert nested json to array of object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, tree

I've a deep nested object like this:

```
{
  'name_1': 'val',
  'name_2': 'val',
  'name_3': {
    'name_4': {
      'name_5': {
        'name_6': 'val',
        'name_7': 'val',
        'name_8': {
          'name_9': 'val'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

> Here key can be anything instead of name_1, name_2, name_3...etc(names key
>   as name_1, name_2.. just for quick understanding)

**I wanted to convert the above json to array of objects in the below mentioned format**

```
[
  { "id": "1", "name": 'name_1: val', "parent_id": "0"},
  { "id": "2", "name": 'name_2: val', "parent_id": "0"},
  { "id": "3", "name": 'name_3', "parent_id": "0"},
  { "id": "4", "name": 'name_4', "parent_id": "3"},
  { "id": "5", "name": 'name_5', "parent_id": "4"},
  { "id": "6", "name": 'name_6: val', "parent_id": "5"},
  { "id": "7", "name": 'name_7: val', "parent_id": "5"},
  { "id": "8", "name": 'name_8', "parent_id": "5"},
  { "id": "9", "name": 'name_9: val', "parent_id": "8"},
]
```

*Any help would be really apprectiated!!*

Comment: please add your problem statement as well.

Comment: I need a logic to convert the json object to array of objects as mentioned in the question..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best way to flatten JS object (keys and values) to a single depth array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44134212/best-way-to-flatten-js-object-keys-and-values-to-a-single-depth-array)

Comment: @GrafiCode, No the object is not deep nested as I mentioned in the question above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take an iterative and recursive approach. (The `id` is stored in an object to keep the same object reference for it and this allows to use it in all nested recursive calls.)

```js
function flat(object, id = { id: 0 }, parent_id = 0) {
    return Object.entries(object).reduce((r, [k, v]) => {
        var name = k + (typeof v === 'string' ? ': ' + v : '');
        r.push({ id: id.id++, name, parent_id });
        if (v && typeof v === 'object') r.push(...flat(v, id, id.id));
        return r;        
    }, []);
}

var data = { name_1: 'val', name_2: 'val', name_3: { name_4: { name_5: { name_6: 'val', name_7: 'val', name_8: { name_9: 'val' } } } } },
    result = flat(data);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: You answer uses name_1, '1' as id, but in my case, key can be any string instead of name_1, name_2

Comment: where do you get `id` from?

Comment: I've added a minor fix to the above answer, Now it works without dependencies with the name_1 ids, Thanks you so much fro your answer