# Iterate nested object to access the key and values in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a nested object which is getting from api response, need to iterate that nested object based keys and values and the structure like this,
Have tried but not getting the expected output.

Code: Api response

```
   {
    "dashboard": "Dashboard",
    "users": "Users",
    "page_builder": "Page Builder",
    "filemanager": {
      "brand": "Brand Images",
      "manufacturer": "Manufacturer Images"
     },
    "catalog": {
      "catalog_product": "Product"
     },
     "coupon": "Coupon",
     "egift": "E-gifting",
     "paymentconfig": {
        "configuration": "Gateway Config",
      },
    "app": {
       "app_general": "General Config",
       "forceupdate_config": "Force Update Config",
     },
    "apppayment": "Kapture Category",
    "kapturecrm": "Vertical Master",
    "phpinfo": "PHP Info"
   }
```

When i tried from my end, am getting the output like this,

Tried sample code:

```
  {Object.keys(roletest).map((key, idx) => (
      <CFormCheck
        id="validationrole_access"
        key={idx}
        name="role_access"
        label={roletest[key]}
        value={roletest[key]}
        onChange={handleChange}
        aria-describedby="inputGroupPrepend"
      />
    ))}
```

My Expected output:

```
    Dashboard
    Users
    Page Builder
    filemanager
    Brand Images
    Manufacturer Images
    catalog
    Product
    Coupon
    E-gifting
    paymentconfig
    Gateway Config
    app
    General Config
    Force Update Config
    Kapture Category
    Vertical Master
    PHP Info
```

My output:

```
  Dashboard
  Users
  Page Builder
  Coupon
  E-gifting
  Kapture Category
  Vertical Master
  PHP Info
```

```
Please do my needs
```

Comment: This is what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44134212/best-way-to-flatten-js-object-keys-and-values-to-a-single-depth-array

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to create a nested list. Which can actually be done quite easily. You were on the right track using an object method to iterate over the properties but [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/entries) might be a little easier.

So, the trick is to make sure you use separate components for the list, and the list items (`List`/`ListItem`). In `List`, as you iterate over the items check if an item is an object. If it is create a new list with the `List` component, otherwise return a list item.

```js
const data={dashboard:"Dashboard",users:"Users",page_builder:"Page Builder",filemanager:{brand:"Brand Images",manufacturer:"Manufacturer Images"},catalog:{catalog_product:"Product"},coupon:"Coupon",egift:"E-gifting",paymentconfig:{configuration:"Gateway Config"},app:{app_general:"General Config",forceupdate_config:"Force Update Config"},apppayment:"Kapture Category",kapturecrm:"Vertical Master",phpinfo:"PHP Info"};

function Example({ data }) {
  return <List list={data} />;
}

function List({ list }) {
  return (
    <ul>
      {Object.entries(list).map((item, key) => {
        return <ListItem key={key} item={item} />;
      })}
    </ul>
  );
}

function ListItem({ item }) {
  const [label, value] = item;
  if (typeof value === 'object') {
    return (
      <li>
        {label}
        <List list={value} />
      </li>
    );
  }
  return <li>{value}</li>;
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example data={data} />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: I need to iterate nested object based keys and values to get parent and child data by the form. Need to display all the iterated values in form input [checkbox]. please do my needs

Comment: I've already covered the details in the question in my answer. I'm not prepared to do all your work for you @nainamohamed.